# what is the usage of 'so' in this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"It is easy to understand the calendar we use today. It was not always so easy."

In this sentence, what does 'so' mean ?

Comment: "so" is used as a synonym of "very" here.

Comment: Are you looking for the syntactic role of the word or its meaning?

Comment: It means it was not as easy as how it is today.

Answer (score 3):

> Simple Definition of *so*
>
> : to a degree that is suggested or stated
>
> : to a great degree
>
> : very or extremely
>
> : without any doubt

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so

In this case, "so" takes the meaning of the first explanation.

*It is easy to understand the calendar we use today. It was not always so easy.* -> It is now easy to understand the calendar but, in the past, understanding the calendar was not as easy as today.